# List layout CSS

Tags: css

I want to display a list like this:

[image]

But my CSS knowledge is not very good, and I'm getting some issues, like:

[image]

I think it's related with float and similar. Tried a few things, but it didn't work. This is the list's HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>
        <img class="itemImg" src="images/foo.jpg" width="230px" height="230px">
        <span class="title">Title title title title</span>
        <a class="rightImage" href="#">
            <img src="images/info_btn.png" width="120px" height="120px">
        </a>
        <span class="textBottom">textBottom textBottom textBottom textBottom </span>
    </li>
```

And the CSS:

```
#list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#list li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;-webkit-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;
}

.itemImg {
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;-webkit-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.rightImage {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
/*  vertical-align: center; */

.title {
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:#00ff00;
}

.textBottom {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 200px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

Any orientation greatly appreciated... thanks.

**Edit:** I also would like that the line "Text text text text" is aligned relative to the bottom right of the parent - not to "Img2". But I have read this kind of alignment is not possible in CSS. How do you handle this?

Comment: Could you provide a demo? [jsBin](http://jsbin.com)

Comment: Well, I tried to reproduce here, although the result is not the same which I got in the mobile browser. http://jsbin.com/uwagix/1/edit

Comment: Yep, that's it. If possible I would like to align the "textBottom" line at the bottom right corner, independently of the right image (is that possible?). But besides of that, it's perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got something very near to what I was looking for. There a few small issues, like, the bottom text starts only bellow the left image - not in the same line (even if it's shorter) and it's also not anchored bottom-right. It's bellow the right image instead. But it looks like I want. This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>
            <img class="itemImg" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Citrus_%C3%97_aurantium_-_fruits_cut.jpg/800px-Citrus_%C3%97_aurantium_-_fruits_cut.jpg" width="230px" height="230px">

            <span class="title">Title title title title title</span>


            <a class="rightImage" href="#">
                <img src="http://jungschirüti.ch/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/info.png" width="120px" height="120px">
            </a>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <span class="textBottom">Text Text Text Text Text </span>

            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
#list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#list li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;-webkit-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #aaaaff;
}

.itemImg {
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;-webkit-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  float:left;
}


.rightImage {

  float: right;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top:20px;
  display:block;

}
/*  vertical-align: center; */

.title {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:#00ff00;
    width:350px;
    display:block;
  float:left;
}

.textBottom {
    float: right;

    background-color:#ff0000;
  width:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need div's in there as well, I would get rid of the spans. Make sure to set floats and widths. Don't forget to clear your floats as well. This is a rough edit, just to convey the idea of divs and floats.

```
<li>
    <img class="itemImg" src="images/foo.jpg" width="230px" height="230px">
    <div class="leftcontainer"><div class="lefttop"><div class="title">Title title title title</div>
    <a class="rightImage" href="#">
        <img src="images/info_btn.png" width="120px" height="120px">
    </a></div>
    <div class="textBottom">textBottom textBottom textBottom textBottom </div></div>
</li>
```

Then add css

```
    #list {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    #list li {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;-webkit-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;
    }
    #list li:after{clear:both}
    .itemImg {
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;-webkit-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;
        margin-right: 10px;
float:left;
width:50px;
    }

    .leftcontainer{float:right,width:200px}//some width

    .rightImage {
        float: right;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top:20px;
width:50px;
    }
    /*  vertical-align: center; */

    .title {
        vertical-align: top;
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color:#00ff00;
float:left;
width:170px
    }

    .textBottom {
        float: right;
        margin-top: 200px;
        background-color:#ff0000;
width:160px;//some width
    }
```